# How to find difference in time in seconds and nanoseconds between two dates?

Tags: c++, datetime, time, c++-chrono

I need to calculate the seconds and nanoseconds between the Unix Epoch (00:00:00 January 1st 1970 UTC) and some date in the future the user will select.

Here is what I managed to find so far looking through other Stack Overflow answers:

```
// seconds and nanoseconds past epoch
auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch();
auto now_ns = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(now);
auto now_sec = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(now);

// output total ns since epoch
qDebug() << now_ns.count() << "ns";
// output total secs since epoch
qDebug() << now_sec.count() << "secs";

auto nano_secs = now_ns.count() - (now_sec.count() * 1000000000);
// output ns minus whole seconds
qDebug() << "nano_secs = " << nano_secs;
```

Using this, I am able to get the result I am looking for for the current date and time but that's not what I need. Let's say for demonstration purposes that future date is 00:00:00 July 1st 2020 UTC. How can I go about calculating this?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time

Comment: `(now_sec.count() * 1000000000)`dont do this - use duration_cast<nanoseconds> and then do the subtraciton.

Comment: `auto nano_secs = now_ns - now_sec;` looks reasonable to me (no `duration_cast` at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++20 this looks like:

```
using namespace std::chrono;
nanoseconds now_ns = sys_days{July/1/2020}.time_since_epoch();
auto now_sec = duration_cast<seconds>(now_ns);
now_ns -= now_sec;
std::cout << now_sec << ", " << now_ns << '\n';
```

Output:

```
1593561600s, 0ns
```

Finding a C++20 std::lib that can do this today is going to be difficult.  However [here is a free, open-source preview of C++20 `<chrono>`](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).

Just add `#include "date/date.h"` and `using namespace date;`, and it works.

If you don't want to use this 3rd party header, [here is the algorithm to convert a `{y, m, d}` triple into a count of days](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html#days_from_civil) since the [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).  Indeed, all `sys_days{July/1/2020}` does is call [`days_from_civil`](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html#days_from_civil) under the hood and put it into a days-precision `chrono::time_point` based on `system_clock`.  From then on the C++11/14 version of `<chrono>` does all of the work.

None of the above computations are dependent on your computer's local timezone setting.